# Issue with Zoho Writer API and cURL Request

Tags: php, curl, zoho

I'm facing an issue with the Zoho Writer API and a cURL request. My goal is to combine PDFs using this API. Unfortunately, I'm encountering an error that I can't resolve.

I've implemented a PHP cURL request as follows:

```
$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$upload_url = "https://zohoapis.com/writer/api/v1/documents/pdf/combine";

$data = [
    'output_settings' => '{"name":"CombinedFile.pdf"}',
    'files[0]' => new CurlFile("download/test2.pdf"),
    'files[1]' => new CurlFile("download/test1.pdf"),
];

$header = array('Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken ' . $token . '');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$oauth2RefreshTokenResponse = json_decode($response, true);
echo $oauth2RefreshTokenResponse;
```

However, when I execute this request, I receive the following error:

[message] => Upload Parameters not configured properly. Please try again.

I have confirmed that my Zoho OAuth token ($token) is correctly set.
The file paths ("download/test1.pdf" and "download/test2.pdf") are accurate.

I have tried different approaches to format the request data, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Can someone please provide insights into what might be causing this error or how to properly format the request for the Zoho Writer API?

Comment: This is the link to the documentation: https://www.zoho.com/writer/help/api/v1/combine-pdfs.html

Comment: Yeah, I am using this document only for reference, I tried everything but no result

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is how you structure the data. Instead of:

```
$data = [
    'output_settings' => '{"name":"CombinedFile.pdf"}',
    'files[0]' => new CurlFile("download/test2.pdf"),
    'files[1]' => new CurlFile("download/test1.pdf"),
];
```

You can try:

```
$data = [
    'output_settings' => '{"name":"CombinedFile.pdf"}',
    'files' => [
         new CurlFile("download/test2.pdf"),
         new CurlFile("download/test1.pdf"),
    ] 
];
```

I can't test this, but it does make more sense this way. You can try it.

Comment: I tried to send the parameter as you suggested still no result.